# for loop plus for in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching, javascript-objects

Why doesn't this code work? I'm trying to loop through the collections of objects and detect if property values match with the source. If property values match, I want to push them into the array. When i console.log in the for in loop, I'm getting undefined, and everything seems to get pushed in to the array. Here is the code:

```
function where(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  // What's in a name?
  for(var i =0; i < collection.length; i++){    
    for(var key in collection){
      if (collection[i][key] === source[key]) {
        arr.push(collection[i]);
      }
    }
  }    
}

  return arr;
}

where([{ first: 'Romeo', last: 'Montague' }, { first: 'Mercutio', last: null }, { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' }], { last: 'Capulet' });
```

My thinking is that this should work but I'm not sure what is going wrong with the code. How can i fix the code?

When I just try to test if the values can be logged im getting undefined, not sure why:

```
function where(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  // What's in a name?
  for(var i =0; i < collection.length; i++){

    for(var key in collection){
          console.log("collection[i][key]:",collection[i][key]);
          console.log("source[key]:", source[key]);



  }

  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Both your inner and outer loops iterate over the same iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add an [i] to the second for loop (

*for(var key in collection **[i]**)*

```
function where(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  // What's in a name?
  for(var i =0; i < collection.length; i++){

    for(var key in collection[i]){
      if(collection[i][key] === source[key])
        {
          arr.push(collection[i]);
        }
  }

  }

  return
```

Comment: you dont need to say "thanks" - accepting the answer acts as a thanks

Comment: i only said thanks because it wouldnt let me accept the answer yet